# SketchFlow Export to Word File and the Order of Objects

Tags: macos, expression-blend, sketchflow, export-to-word

i have made a prototype in SketchFlow which is found in Expression Blend 3. As my designer can not use the published .exe version (Due to being on a Mac) I have to export the application to Word. This works great apart from the order being somewhat odd.

What determines the order in which objects get exported into the Word document and more importantly how can i change this order to what i want it to be?

Thanks,
Kohan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the Word export is set to output the Sketchflow Map first, the initially generated screen second and the custom-made screens alphabetically. I'll ask around and see if there is a way to modify that.

As an alternative, you could create the Sketchflow prototype as a Silverlight app and then your designer could view the ouput as a .xap hosted on an html page.

Comment: Great, that is something i will definitely consider next time. Failing that - from what you say i could also prefix a number to the subsequent pages so that they get sorted in the order of my choice. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the order of pages in the word document is indeed: Map, Navigation screens in alphaetical order, component screens in alphabetical order. Currently, the only way to force a particular order is to prefix the screen names appropriately.

Adam is also right that a good way to give anybody access to a prototype is to make the prototype in Silverlight rather than WPF. This lets you post the prototype on the web, and lets users on a Mac review them too.